# Windows context menu option for "Copy a link to file"?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, context-menu, hyperlink

Is there a way to add a context menu option for copying a link to a file to include in a plaintext email (or something that accomplishes the same thing in Outlook) for Windows 7?

For example, if I have a mounted Windows network share `\\foo` and there was a file on it `bar baz`, I would like to get `file:///\\foo\bar%20baz`. Ideally this would work with mounted FTP drives, etc., but what I really would like it for is network shares.

Shift-right click gives a "Copy as path" option, but this will generate a path like `"Q:\bar baz"`, not `file:///\\foo\bar%20baz`. Outlook has a link function, but it does not work with plaintext email.